# Cart Throb display Discount amount on order

Tags: cartthrob

I want to display the dioscont from a coupon on the order form in Cart Throb.
Is this possible?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" entry_id="{segment_3}" show_future_entries="yes" dynamic="no"}
Discount: {order_discount}<br />
Coupon Code: {order_coupons}<br />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

When viewing an invoice with the code above I can get the {order_coupons} to display but {order_discount} is always empty and not showing the dollar amount that was discounted.

I also have the field mapped properly in CT settings > orders

Comment: This code should work for you. Only thing that could trip you up is statuses, if you're using them. So would you need to set status="paid" or status="not none" to display your results? That wouldn't explain why you're getting coupons but not a discount amount.

Comment: if {order_coupons} shows the coupon code but {order_discount} is blank it should have nothing to do with the status.  If it was a status issue neither would show.